# Sort items in datatable

Tags: c#

I have a datatable with one column that contain names.I want to load combobox with datatable such that names should be in alphabetic order for eg:first name starts with a.
second name starts with b.How can i sort data in datatable.Can anybody help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a DataView:

```
DataTable dt; //comes from somewhere...
DataView dv = new DataView(dt)
dv.Sort = "Name ASC";
foreach(DataRowView drv in dv)
    //....
```

Comment: very simple and such a nice solution.

Comment: I think that should be DataRowView instead of DataRow: 
foreach(DataRowView dr in dv)

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1**

```
    // orderby "FistName" column
    EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> query = 
                    from order in datatable.AsEnumerable()
                    orderby datatable.Field<string>("FirstName")
                    select datatable;

    DataView view = query.AsDataView();

    // bind to your combobox
    combobox.DataSource = view;
    combobox.DataBind()
```

**Method 2**: if using DataSets

```
    DataTable datatable = dataSet.Tables["yourDataTable"];    
    DataView view = datatable .AsDataView();

    view.Sort = "FirstName desc, LastName desc";

    combobox.DataSource = view;
    combobox.DataBind();
```

Reference : [**Sorting with DataView (LINQ to DataSet)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669083.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

[Here's the answer](http://www.debugging.com/bug/10219) that you're looking for.

```
DataTable MyDataTable;
const string SortByClause = "[SomeCol] ASC";
MyDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = SortByClause ;
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article131.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use an typed dataset 
create a datatable in precising type of data
for example i have create a dsAppointment

```
 DsAppointment dsAppointmentTmp = new DsAppointment();
 DsAppointment dsAppointment = new DsAppointment();
//add all appointment
 dsAppointmentTmp.Appointment.AddAppointmentRow(name,start,end,body)
//use select(filter,sort(name of columns)
DataRow[] rows1 = dsAppointmentTmp.Tables[0].Select(string.Empty, dsAppointmentTmp.Tables[0].Columns[1].ToString());

            foreach (DataRow thisRow in rows1)
            {
                    dsAppointment.Tables[0].Rows.Add(thisRow.ItemArray);

            }
```

//return dsAppointment sorted
                return dsAppointment;