# Sort grid view programmatically

Tags: asp.net

How to sort gridview programmatically

Answer (score 0):

If you are pulling records from a database, your query should include an ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 0):

Sort the view instead... [Sort items in datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294180/sort-items-in-datatable)