# Sorting in datatable

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

I have a list of records in database class

```
D1.1: First
D2.12: second
D1.14: third
D2.8: fourth
D2.2: fifth
D2.3: fifth
D1.7: fifth
D2: fifth
D1.5: fifth
```

How should I sort by taking the consideration the codes of D like 1.1, 2.12. 1.14 etc ?

The output required should be below.

```
D1.1: First  
D1.14: third  
D1.5: fifth
D1.7: fifth    
D2: fifth
D2.12: second
D2.2: fifth
D2.3: fifth
D2.8: fourth
```

Comment: Why is `D1.14` after `D1.5` but `D2.12` comes before `D2.2` ?? Once (for D1) you seem to be sorting numerically, the other time (for D2) you seem to be sorting string-like ..... what do you really want???

Comment: Yes, You are correct. Modified the output.

Comment: +1 for correcting the output. Thanks marc_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear exactly from your post how the data is in the actual table, but if it's in the field formatted like that then you could order it by using SUBSTRING. Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @test AS TABLE (
data varchar(50)
)

INSERT @test VALUES ('D1.1: First')
INSERT @test VALUES ('D2.12: second')
INSERT @test VALUES ('D1.14: third')
INSERT @test VALUES ('D2.8: fourth')
INSERT @test VALUES ('D2.2: fifth')
INSERT @test VALUES ('D2.3: fifth')
INSERT @test VALUES ('D1.7: fifth')
INSERT @test VALUES ('D2: fifth')
INSERT @test VALUES ('D1.5: fifth')

SELECT data FROM @test
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(data,2,CHARINDEX(':',data,0)-2)
```

Result:

```
data
--------------------------------------------------
D1.1: First
D1.14: third
D1.5: fifth
D1.7: fifth
D2: fifth
D2.12: second
D2.2: fifth
D2.3: fifth
D2.8: fourth
```

Comment: Downvote if you feel it's not helpful. I did read the question and understand that you're talking about a datatable in C#, but my point is that from your original question it's not clear how the data is held or originally structured. My approach to the information I had was to order the data in SQL thus populating the datatable with the data in the correct format in the first place. If the datatable isn't populated from a SQL statement then obviously this is no good for you.

Comment: No, we have records at front end only. Thus, it does not make sense to go in database. That's why I did not include other tags!! I need to do it in front end only.

Comment: Sorry, I am not interested in this suggestion.

Comment: Fair enough. Take a look at this instead then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294180/sort-items-in-datatable

Comment: It is not taking into consideration for numeric values. Not interested in this approach. It will create bugs.

Comment: OK, how about implementing IComparable? Take a look at this for an example. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx

Comment: Take a look at this: http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2005/03/06/implementing-icomparer-for-sorting-custom-objects/ or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163922/sort-a-custom-class-list

Comment: No. it's again not considering the numeric values in the string. Again, not interested in this approach.

Comment: You're reading too literally, I didn't say that was the perfect solution for you to copy and paste, but it is the correct way for you to implement sorting in a class. You just need to write a compare function that chops up the strings into the numeric format you need to sort on, like I did before in the SQL statement. There is no way you can achieve the results you want without some string manipulation.

Comment: May be you are right....I will wait for others to respond for this query. Meanwhile if u can give some sample code for the string manipulation in front end only.

Comment: `string data = "D1.1: First";`
`data = data.Substring(1, data.IndexOf(":")-1);`

Comment: You're having a laugh aren't you? I tell you what, why don't I just come over there and write your app for you while you sit back with your feet up and have a nice coffee and some cake? I mean hey, it is nearly the weekend. Dude, I'm not being funny, but you've got more than enough information there to go on. If you can't get something working out of that then I'd seriously consider a change of career.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you would have come up with the complete answer. My tags are C# only and not sql srever.

Comment: It's ur mistake from the beginning when u replied using sql server